# nginx proxy_pass with vue-cli too slow

Tags: vue.js, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using nginx **proxy_pass** with **vue** (**docker** container)
when I connect with direct port (ex. http://127.0.0.1:4000) this works very well and fast.

but when I connect with 443 port with domain (ex. https://example.com) always failed with too slow javascript loading.

**https://example.com/js/app.7f6baa34.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)**

[image: console]

[image: network]

```
  server {
      listen 443 ssl;
      ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com/example.com.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com/example.com.key;
      server_name www.example.com;
      client_max_body_size 100M;

      location / {
          proxy_set_header        Host $host;
          proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
          proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
      }


      access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

It caused by lack of server memory.